# Error Importing GTK

Tags: python, import, gtk, pygtk

I'm running Python 2.7, with the latest version of GTK installed.

I'm trying to import gtk with the following line of code:

```
import gtk
```

It is throwing the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\GTKTutorial\tutorial.py", line 3, in 
>       import gtk   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gtk__init__.py", line 40, in
>   
>       from gtk import _gtk ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified
>   procedure could not be found.

How do I fix this? import pygtk is working, and I have Glade 3.8.0 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you get the PyGTK installer from? Try using this one: http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.22/pygtk-all-in-one-2.22.6.win32-py2.7.msi

Comment: That is where I got the PyGTK installer from, only I had to install each component separately. When I used the all-in-one, pygtk would not import.

Comment: I used the installer I linked to on a fresh XP install recently, right after the [Python 2.7.2 installer](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/python-2.7.2.msi), and it worked perfectly. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

I just spent 3 days debugging this issue on my computer. This problem can have many root causes because importing gtk actually causes a lot of DLLs being loaded. If any of them fails, you get the same error message. For me, the break-through was

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

which I used to profile the command

python -i -c "import gtk"

On my PC, a wrong version of zlib1.dll was in the system32 directory, which prevented the right one in gtk\bin from loading. And it did that even though the first entry in my path pointed to gtk\bin.

I deleted the zlib1.dll from system32 (the application that put it there deserves to die) and the import worked fine. Your problem may be different, but dependency walker probably can give you a hint on what is going wrong.

Windows can have other reasons for loading a DLL other than the one you put in your directory or path. I found the blog

http://www.davidlenihan.com/2007/07/winsxs.html

useful. It describes Microsoft's solution for managing many versions of DLLs, and how to troubleshoot problems with it.